# What is a valid type signature for the `Any-∃` exercise?

Tags: agda, plfa

```
#### Exercise `Any-∃`

Show that `Any P xs` is isomorphic to `∃[ x ∈ xs ] P x`.
```

Leaving aside the fact that `∃[ x ∈ xs ] P x` is not even [valid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356229/how-to-import-the-%E2%88%83-syntax/56366739) - only `Σ[ x ∈ xs ] P x` could be valid, none of the type signatures I've tried typecheck for that particular problem.

```
Any-∃ : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} {xs : List A} → Any P xs ≃ Σ[ x ∈ xs ] P x
```

```
List A !=< Set _a_1582 of type Set
when checking that the expression xs has type Set _a_1582
```

The most obvious thing here fails. I sort of understand what the question is trying to ask me here, but I am not sure what the structure `∃[ x ∈ xs ] P x` is supposed to be.

This is the penultimate exercise in the [Lists chapter](https://plfa.github.io/Lists/) of the PLFA book.

Comment: I thought it might be `∃[ x ] ((x ∈ xs) * P x)`, but I can't get this to typecheck...

Comment: That's the right idea but rather than `_*_` you should use `_×_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book has been corrected now:

Exercise `Any-∃` (practice)

Show that `Any P xs` is isomorphic to `∃[ x ] (x ∈ xs × P x)`.